# list index out of range when upgrating python/django

Tags: python, django

```
        fa = Fa.objects.filter(fa_name = tag)[0]
```

It was working in python 2.7 and django 1.8 but now that I migrated to django 2.2 and python 3.6 its not working

Comment: That means that element or element you're trying access is not within range of the list and just doesn't exist.

Comment: could it be it should be double equal with python 3 , because that was working in python 2

Comment: that's not part of the syntactical changes, and `==` is not an assignment operator but comparative operator.

Comment: strange it was working in django 1.8 and python 2.7 I had to change to fa_name__icontains but i want exact match not icontains

Comment: is this missing more code?

Comment: fa = Fa.objects.filter(fa_name__icontains = tag)[0] this works, but iu want equal match not icontains

Comment: what's difference between fa_name and fa_name_icontains your issue lies somewhere within that

Comment: hi issue is fa_name = " kfsf" where tag  = "kfsf" so there is additional space in fa_name, thats why equals not working but icontains is.

Comment: Please share the entire error message and provide a [mcve].

Comment: you're accessing element 0, at the end and since they are not equal you get that error.

Comment: yes. because fa_name has spaces at begining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the first if no data then `None` you should use `first` method:

```
fa = Fa.objects.filter(fa_name = tag).first()
```

It will return you `None` if you have no data and if you do have then it will return the first element

If you want to avoid any `None` values then you should check before executing it:

```
if Fa.objects.filter(fa_name = tag).count() > 0:
    fa = fa = Fa.objects.filter(fa_name = tag)[0]
```